# Simple VB.NET using Google Search API?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, search, google-api

Can anyone point me to a good, simple, example of a Google API (AJAX Search API I suppose?) that can be implemented in VB.net (2008)?   I have tried to sign up for a Google API key but it wants a URL from which the search will be executed from.  I dont have a URL for this example.  I tried http://localhost but then was told by a colleague that she got a "Invalid Key" error.   A simple working example would be awesome.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running a Google API locally for development or test purposes, you can use an internal IP address - it doesn't have to be URL that's exposed to the Internet. For example, I have development machines running the Google Maps API using addresses in the 192.168.0.xxx range. This allows them to be accessed from any other machine on the internal network. Obviously you need a fixed IP for this.

Comment: OK.  I will give that a shot.  My IP's are fixed, internally.  This should work.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the Google API TOS allows for .net development.  I read that in a newsgroup article recently.

Comment: really?? i'd be surprised to find this true.

Comment: As far as I can tell from the terms of service listed on the Google site, there is no limitation on the platform you can use when developing with Google APIs. There are restrictions on how you use the APIs - eg you cannot place the free version of Google Maps behind restricted or paid for access.